# Using keepalived in two subnets - Or alternative

Tags: redhat, keepalived

I want to create a failover cluster with two redhat machines using keepalived.
Unfortunately the two members of the cluster will be hosted on different locations with different IP-subnets (10.1.x.x on the first, and 10.2.x.x on the second site).

How can I do this?
Or is there an alternative I could use?

The server will run as a proxy, DNS and FTP server for our company.
We want it to be hosted on the two different locations just for redundancy reasons.

Hope you can help and thx!

Comment: This won't work. You could do the load-balancing on a VPS, or (perhaps better) move the DNS and FTP to VPS systems altogether. What is the proxy part supposed to do? For outgoing proxying? Having that failove makes no sense, just let each site use its own proxy.

Comment: Are you using a unicast_peer?  And does your router allow the floating IP to show up in both subnets?